# Is Occitan a single language or have its different dialects become separate languages?

Tags: romance-languages, dialects, occitan

The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occitan_language) for the language mentions a 'controversy' about whether it is a language, macrolanguage or language family.

Is there an official status for the language and what are the arguments for it not being a language?

Comment: Does it have an army?

Comment: Or to put it differently: "language" vs "dialect" is not a meaningful question in linguistics.

Comment: The problem is that we don't know what you mean by "official status". Aranese is statutorily recognized in Catalonia as an official language, but Catalonia has no position on Provençal. So are you asking about statury recognitions?

Comment: The wikipedia article you link specifically addresses the questions "Is there an official status for the language and what are the arguments for it not being a language" - given that, what more are you looking for in an answer?

Comment: Sorry, I'm looking for the general distinction between a language and a dialect and a language family; what makes it one rather than the other?

Comment: In linguistics the term 'dialect' is used to indicate that varieties are mutually intelligible: NZ English and Irish English are mutually intelligible so they are described as dialects of one language (usually just called 'English'). Two varieties are referred to as different languages if they are *not* mutually intelligible.

Comment: [cont.] So you need to find speakers of these different varieties of Occitan (ones with no prior exposure to each other's variety) and bring them together and observe how well they can communicate. This is all easy to say, but it can be very difficult to come to firm conclusions!

Comment: Wikipedia, as great as it is, it not necessarily a reliable resource. Just because they say it doesn't make it so. Gascon and Nicois, though both are considered dialects of Occitan, are not mutually intelligible. Does this make them separate languages? I'd lean towards yes, even if they are part of a language continuum.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I'm looking for the general distinction between a language and a dialect and a language family; what makes it one rather than the other?

#### [How are languages and dialects distinguished from one another?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/810/how-are-languages-and-dialects-distinguished-from-one-another)

There is no consistent, scientific distinction between two dialects of a single language, and two separate languages (with a common ancestor). It's most often a political distinction. Some highly mutually intelligible lects are considered different languages (e.g. [Serbian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serbian_language) and [Croatian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Croatian_language)) whereas others with extremely low degrees of mutual intelligibility are considered the same language (e.g. the *Valais* dialect of [Walser German](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walser_German) and [Standard German](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_German)).

In linguistic circles, the Romance dialect continuum native to the [historical Occitania](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occitania), having evolved from Old Occitan, are all considered dialects of one language: Occitan. These are divided into various groupings of dialects, but they're all considered Occitan. Occitan and Catalan are often grouped together when discussing the romance languages, separate from the sandwiching Iberian and Gallo-Romance groups:

[image]

*Languages* are to *language families* what *dialects* are to *languages* - groupings of genetically related lects, just at different degrees of magnification. Sometimes other intermediate subgroupings are used, like *macro-language*, *sub-family*, *sub-dialect*, etc. These kinds of terms are akin to the use of *Species*, *Genus*, *Family* etc in biological [taxonomic ranking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxonomic_rank).

On a political level, since Occitan is spoken in southern France, Italy's Occitan Valleys, Monaco, and Spain's Val d'Aran, the governments of these countries/regions are the relevant political entities:

- In **Catalonia**, [Aranese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aranese_dialect) (the subdialect of Gascon spoken in Val d'Aran) is an official language, and since September 2010, the Parliament of Catalonia has considered Aranese Occitan to be the officially preferred language for use in the Val d'Aran.
- Occitan has no official status in **France**, the country having a very [unfortunate history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vergonha) in its treatment of minority languages...
- French is the sole official language of **Monaco**.
- In **Italy**, Occitan is officially recognised as "historical language minorities" by the [Law no. 482/1999](http://www.parlamento.it/parlam/leggi/99482l.htm)

  - **Piedmont** "promotes", without recognising, Occitan (as well as Franco-Provençal, French and Walser) ([Legge regionale 7 aprile 2009, n. 11, Art. 1](http://arianna.consiglioregionale.piemonte.it/base/coord/c2009011.html))

Comment: Can you comment on the mutual intelligibility between these Occitan and Catalan varieties?

Comment: One thing to point out sociolinguistically is that many people speak the variety called Catalan as L1 (in Catalonia (Spain) and Andorra and Alghero (Sardinia)) but few (nobody?) in France currently speaks Gascon or Provencal or Nicoise as L1 (though many have accents and many study then in school).